# Hibernate Duplicate database entries

Tags: java, hibernate

I am currently trying to edit my first database with Hibernate.
I have two tables: testobject_typ and testobject.
A test object has a test object type.

The problem is: When I write a new test object to the database, a new test object type is created with a new ID, even if an entry with a matching name already exists.

How do I prevent Hibernate from creating a new entry and using an existing entry with the same name instead?

My Java classes look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "testobject")
public class TestObject {

@Id
@Column(name="testobject_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name = "mc_id")
private int mcid;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="testobjecttyp_id")
private TestObjectTyp testObjectTyp;
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "testobject_typ")
public class TestObjectTyp {

@Id
@Column(name="testobjecttyp_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
```

---

TestObjectService

```
@Override
public synchronized boolean addTestObject(TestObject testObject){
    if (testobjectDao.testObjectExists(testObject.getMcid())) {
        return false;
    } else {
        testobjectDao.addTestObject(testObject);
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

TestobjectDAO

```
public class TestobjectDao implements ITestobjectDao {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public void addTestObject(TestObject testObject) {
    entityManager.persist(testObject);
}

@Override
public boolean testObjectExists(int mcid) {
    String hql = "FROM TestObject as to WHERE to.mcid = ?";
    int count = entityManager.createQuery(hql).setParameter(1, mcid).getResultList().size();
    return count > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

How i create the entity:

```
TestObject testObject = new TestObject();
TestObjectTyp testobjectTyp = new TestObjectTyp(); 
testobjectTyp.setName(TestobjectTypes.specification); 
testObject.setTestObjectTyp(testobjectTyp);
testObject.setMcid(110);
testObject.setName("Test");
iDatabaseService.addTestObject(testObject);
```

Comment: Could you add your java code used to create the new test object ?

Comment: are you creating a new testObjectTyp or finding by name if exist in db?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added the missing classes.

Comment: the point is how are you creating the TestObject?
i suppose new TestObject()?
and then testObject.setTestObjectTyp(new TestObjectType())?

Comment: Yes, I use new. The id of the TestObjectType is null                   
        TestObject testObject = new TestObject();
        TestObjectTyp testobjectTyp = new TestObjectTyp();
        testobjectTyp.setName(TestobjectTypes.specification);
        testObject.setTestObjectTyp(testobjectTyp);
        testObject.setMcid(110);
        testObject.setName("Test");
        iDatabaseService.addTestObject(testObject);

Comment: Referring to the answer below, I assume that I first have to read the corresponding ID from the database? I thought that would make Hibernate for me.

Comment: Yes you need to load your type from the database and set it. Hibernate doesn't do that on it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment:

yes hibernate will create a new row in db if you just create a new istance of an entity and then save it (through cascade in this case).

instead of doing

```
TestObjectTyp testobjectTyp = new TestObjectTyp(); 
testobjectTyp.setName(TestobjectTypes.specification);
```

you should query db for that TestObjectTyp

e.g.

```
"FROM TestobjectTypes tot WHERE tot.name = ?";
```

the difference is that now hibernate know about this TestobjectTypes (it's called a managed entity, meaning that changes on this entity will get reflected on db) and will know that it's already present in db

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate doesn't get that entities with the same `name` should be the same entity. You set the cascade type to `CascadeType.ALL`, which makes Hibernate insert new entities when it encounters entities which don't have an ID assigned.

I would suggest:

- Checking if an entity exists with the same name (by executing a Hibernate query, something like `select from TestObjectTyp where name = :name`). If it doesn't exist, insert a new TestObjectTyp and use that instead.
- Optionally, adding a unique constraint to the `name` field, if you want to prevent objects with the same name existing.

Other alternative is to use the name as the Primary key (instead of a generated ID) but it's generally a bad practice to use PK's that have any meaning ;)

Comment: I thought that would do Hibernate for me. I will try your approach.